# How to create tabindex groups?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I'm trying to make tabindex groups where pressing tab in a group it allways rotates in that group until the other group is focused via javascript or manually.

**Question:** Is it possible to do this without JavaScript, if not how can I achieve this?

Here is [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SrVEc/)

**HTML code**:

```
<fieldset>
    <input tabindex="1"/>
    <input tabindex="2"/>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
    <input tabindex="1"/>
    <input tabindex="2"/>
</fieldset>
```

**EDIT:** I would prefer iframe to be last resort to solve this, it would be very hard to implement iframe at this stage of development in my application.

---

### This is what I came up

This is pretty messy code, but this is what I came up. Adding `data-tabgroup` and `data-tabgroupindex` to `input` elements will correctly tab them without going out of the group.

As [steveax](https://stackoverflow.com/users/557612/steveax) pointed out in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18543570/how-to-create-tabindex-groups?noredirect=1#comment27276672_18543570) this is not suggested for users without keyboards or in any regular HTML form situation where this isn't really necessary.

Example in **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/skmasq/8XWab/)**
**Used libraries**:

- lodash.js
- jquery 1.8.3

HTML Code:

```
<div>
    <input data-tabgroup="first" data-tabgroupindex="1" />
    <input data-tabgroup="first" data-tabgroupindex="2" />
    <input data-tabgroup="first" data-tabgroupindex="3" />
    <input data-tabgroup="first" data-tabgroupindex="4" />
</div>
<div>
    <input data-tabgroup="second" data-tabgroupindex="1" />
    <input data-tabgroup="second" data-tabgroupindex="3" />
    <input data-tabgroup="second" data-tabgroupindex="2" />
    <input data-tabgroup="second" data-tabgroupindex="4" />
</div>
```

JavaScript code:

```
function isNumber(n) {
    return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}
$(document).on('keydown', '[data-tabgroup]', function (e) {
    // TODO
    // Get elements tabgroup [DONE]
    // Find element position by tabgroupindex
    // Check if pressed shift+tab or tab
    // Check if it's first or the last element
    // Check which is next element to focus
    // Focus appropriate element

    if (e.which === 9) {

        var indexNode = $(e.target);
        var nodeIndex = indexNode.data("tabgroupindex");
        var tabgroup = indexNode.data("tabgroup");
        var tabgroupNodes = $("[data-tabgroup='" + tabgroup + "']");
        var tabgroupIndexes = [];
        _.each(tabgroupNodes, function (item) {
            tabgroupIndexes.push(+$(item).data("tabgroupindex"));
        });
        tabgroupIndexes = _(tabgroupIndexes).compact()
            .sortBy(function (num) {
            return num;
        }).value();
        if (isNumber(nodeIndex)) {
            if (e.which === 9) if (e.shiftKey) {
                var nextElement = tabgroupIndexes[tabgroupIndexes.indexOf(nodeIndex) - 1];
                if (typeof(nextElement) === "undefined") {
                    $("[data-tabgroup='" + tabgroup + "'][data-tabgroupindex='" + tabgroupIndexes[tabgroupIndexes.length - 1] + "']").focus();
                    console.log($("[data-tabgroup='" + tabgroup + "'][data-tabgroupindex='" + tabgroupIndexes[tabgroupIndexes.length - 1] + "']").get(0));
                } else {
                    $("[data-tabgroup='" + tabgroup + "'][data-tabgroupindex='" + nextElement + "']").focus();
                }
            } else {

                var nextElement = tabgroupIndexes[tabgroupIndexes.indexOf(nodeIndex) + 1];

                if (typeof(nextElement) === "undefined") {
                    console.log("Im in ")
                    $("[data-tabgroup='" + tabgroup + "'][data-tabgroupindex='" + tabgroupIndexes[0] + "']").focus();
                    console.log($("[data-tabgroup='" + tabgroup + "'][data-tabgroupindex='" + tabgroupIndexes[0] + "']").get(0))
                } else {
                    $("[data-tabgroup='" + tabgroup + "'][data-tabgroupindex='" + nextElement + "']").focus();
                }
            }

        } else {
                $("[data-tabgroup='" + tabgroup + "'][data-tabgroupindex='" + tabgroupIndexes[0] + "']").focus();

        }
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: In general it's not wise to muck with the natural tab indices. At best, you'll surprise users; at worst you'll strand users who only navigate with the keyboard (think screenreader users).

Comment: @steveax I have a SPA where I use tabindex to make div's focus-able. So when I open up filtering input group on the last input I completely lose where focus is. So in my situation it is very essential I restrict tabs only in this area.

Comment: @steveax And I have one group per page, those pages are not displayed at the same time on screen in no way.

Comment: It may be appropriate in your case - the "focused manually" line made me think to caution you to remember that not all users have the ability to use a mouse.

Comment: @steveax Thank you I forgot to think about that. But luckily in my case a mouse is requirement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JQuery UI has a the [`:tababble`](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabbable-selector/) selector which could help you out here.

1. Select all the last tab selectable elements of a group.
2. Capture the tab input.
3. Manually select the first tab selectable sibling.
4. (Likewise for Shift + tab on first tab selectable element.)

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SrVEc/4/)

#### JavaScript

```
$(function(){
    // Listen for TAB on last child.
    $('fieldset :tabbable:last-child').on('keydown', function(e) {
        if (e.which == 9) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).siblings(':tabbable').eq(0).focus();
        } 
    });

    // Listen for SHIFT + TAB on first child.
    $('fieldset :tabbable:first-child').on('keydown', function(e) {
        if (e.shiftKey && e.which == 9) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).siblings(':tabbable').eq(-1).focus();
        } 
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks this is what I was looking for in first place.